# MySQL / Mariadb - Duplicate entry '1' for key *****

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, typeorm

So I migrated a NodeJS backend from express to NestJS + TypeORM

But now I keep getting this error:

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'IDX_b37305d1c6376498a51b97ce1a

But where ever I look in the database, I cannot find a index or foreign key with that hash.

My understanding was to just reset the indexes, but it doesn't work this time.

> easyNFT-api | [Nest] 19  - 06/28/2022, 10:57:12 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Duplicate entry '1' for key 'IDX_b37305d1c6376498a51b97ce1a'
> easyNFT-api | QueryFailedError: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'IDX_b37305d1c6376498a51b97ce1a'
> easyNFT-api |     at Query.onResult (/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:158:37)
> easyNFT-api |     at Query.execute (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14)
> easyNFT-api |     at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
> easyNFT-api |     at PacketParser.onPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
> easyNFT-api |     at PacketParser.executeStart (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
> easyNFT-api |     at Socket. (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
> easyNFT-api |     at Socket.emit (node:events:537:28)
> easyNFT-api |     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
> easyNFT-api |     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
> easyNFT-api |     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
> easyNFT-api |     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

The strace doesn't show what table the error is in, so because I have about 15 tables, how do I find the error / solution for this??

Thanks

**Question 1**:

[image]

I Looped through all the tables, but cannot find an index like that.

**Question 2**:

I had these errors before, and could always fix them by removing all indexes, but because I cannot find an index like that this time, thats the problem :(

Comment: how have you looked?  `show create table yourtablename` will most helpfully show indexes with their names; do that on all 15 tables

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "reset the indexes"?  what exactly is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @ysth please see updated topic

Comment: strongly recommend you not use a database UI that hides things from you.  just do show create table in a command line client (or if you must, in your UI) and look at the actual results.

Comment: Run the queries one by one on the database, but no strange results coming out of it..

Can I please ask a question about it?? Does this mean, it tries to create a row with index 1, while a row with index 1 already exists?

Comment: @ysth Can we make a deal, if I pay you some crypto to help me out in a teamviewer call?

Comment: Thats my problem... I cannot find any table using that key, as either index or foreign key :( It just 'seems' to be stuck in memory or somehting... Don't understand

Comment: What is the code that leads to the error being produce? Probably the `INSERT` code.

Comment: @FanoFN Its when booting up the NestJS app..

I think, the 'models' are to different then the actual database.. But what I hate, is that mySQL stack trace doesn't give me the table name that has the problem :(

Comment: @FanoFN You feel like helping me our real quick maybe? I Will try to make it worth your time.. I just really need advice from someone that understands...

Comment: Sorry @DutchKevv , I can't commit to that at the moment. I'm just browsing some question here while waiting for my next assignment. I'm afraid that when the assignment come, I'll have no choice to leave everything else that I was doing and we may not solve anything on your part. Anyway, I think you should focus on the codes while booting the NestJS app since it's the one returning error. Just any of the MySQL code.

Comment: Thanks for giving heads up... To be honest if done 15 years of JS + etc, but I have these kind of problems over and over again.. So there is something I'm missing...

If you do got 15-30 minutes of free time, please let me know... I'm happy to just hear your opinion of the code

Comment: This may help you find the key `SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='IDX_b37305d1c6376498a51b97ce1a';` . Run that in your MySQL db an see if you can find anything. By the way, the source of the error might be when your `INSERT` query sends two rows where the value for a `PRIMARY KEY` column is the same. [Something like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ceade75cd3bc994ee048905bebc0114c)

Comment: Tried it in both local + development environment, both giving empty results back..

But I do understand your follow up point.

Because the query you send me returned nothing, I also think it has somehting todo with my NestJS app starting up and wanting to inject a new row (duplicate)...

Thanks for helping, I just really really wished I didn't get stuck in Web/JS world for so long.... This is f*cking me up so hard

Comment: Hmm Doesn't exist in mysql - are you sure your start up app isn't attempting to create this failing so it doesn't get to mysql at all